# Selecting referenced column entries with SQLITE3: Ignored WHERE-clause

Tags: sqlite, where-clause

I have the following sqlite3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE bilder (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL);
```

Data:

```
__id__
8
9
10
11
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE combos (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL);
```

Data:

```
__id__
1
2
3
4
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE combo_bild (combo_id int not null references combos(id), bild_id int not null references bilder(id), display_nummer int, unique (combo_id, bild_id));
```

Data:

```
__combo_id__|__bild_id__|__display_nummer__
1            8           1
1            9           2
2            8           1
2            10          2
```

When I process the following query:

```
SELECT combo_id, bild_id FROM combo_bild WHERE combo_id > 1;
```

I get (as expected):

```
__combo_id__|__bild_id__|__display_nummer__
2            8           1
2            10          2
```

However, when I use the following query:

```
SELECT combo_id, bild_id FROM combo_bild WHERE bild_id > 9;
```

I get

```
__combo_id__|__bild_id__|__display_nummer__

1            8           1
1            9           2
2            8           1
2            10          2
```

Why is the WHERE clause ignored? Thanks for looking at it, Dani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WHERE clause is not ignored.
All the values in the `bild_id` column are larger than `9` because they are strings, not numbers.

Check how you import the data.

To fix the table, execute something like this:

```
UPDATE combo_bild SET bild_id = CAST(bild_id AS INT);
```

Comment: Why are the entries of bild_id strings? I declared them as int (see create statement).

Comment: Indeed: I use "$check->bindParam(':ID', $id, SQLITE3_TEXT);" - instead of SQLITE3_INTEGER - but why doesn't the DBMS complain since id was declared as int? AND: Thank's a lot for the tipp!

Comment: Does it need something like "$conn->exec( 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;' );" to properly check my entries?

Comment: Or would it be better if combined with an integrity check? How can I make sure the DBMS checks if an entry is according to it's declaration?

Comment: In SQLite, column types [do not have the effect](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) that you think they have.

Comment: So it seems ... however when studying chapter 3.4 I think for INT-columns (with INT affinity), shouldn't '34' be converted to integer value 34?